# Questions about Alvandi large format cameras

Tags: equipment-recommendation, landscape, camera-recommendation, large-format, architecture

I recently stumbbled upon this large format camera manufacturer called [Mr. Alvandi](https://www.mr-alvandi.com/), in Iran.

They produce a variety of medium and large format cameras (679, 4x5, 5x7, 8x10, 6x17) since about 15 years. Apparently all parts are made "in house". I think they *look* great and seem quite functional but to my surprise, I found very little information (or even sample shots) from actual owners.

I would be very interested to know — if anyone here owns one of these — how practical they are to use for landscape and architecture photography.

- Is it well built?
- How do the movements feel? Are they easy to use and precise?
- What do you use yours for?
- What do you like/dislike about it?
- etc.

Basically, I am after any insight from current or past owners.

I own a Sinar F2 (4x5) and while it is a great camera, I find it very impractical for shooting landscape because of its weight and size. It's fine if I can get to a view point with my car but I hate to carry it around on my back (especially in the mountains, where I live). It's just way too heavy, which is why I am looking for a much lighter alternative and got interested in these Alvandi cameras.

Comment: After seeing that link, now I want one - even if I don't know why!  If the brand is relatively unknown, I'd be tempted to reach out to the photographers mentioned in the "Alvandi club" page on that site and see if they'd share their opinions.

Comment: @PeterM Maybe because they look so nice? Yes, I thought about that too and I will try to reach out to some of them via their website / flickr / social networks links.

Comment: I'm on a quest for a good 6x17, so they do interest me. (I did just get a 120 6x12 Holga, but it's a Holga - and I knew that going in)

Comment: The 6x17 looks like a nice option for landscapes. They also make 6x17 Graflok backs that can be mounted on the Panoral 57 (if 5x7 is a format of interest for you) and 6x12 backs that mount on the Panoral 45. I'll update my question or post an answer whenever I manage to get some useful owners' feedbacks.

Comment: Everything made in house means spare parts will be hard to come by. That’s not what I would want in a field camera, but of course YMMV.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens a useful feedback from a long-time owner would be to know that they are so well built that they don't break, so no spare parts issue ;) But you are right, this is something that should be taken into account.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens Being made in house, in a country that has various sanctions imposed on it could also mean that the parts are simpler to manufacture, and hence simpler to duplicate for replacement.  However, if the company is still in business then going straight back to them for parts would be reasonable (OTOH I have some German cameras from the 1950's where the manufacturer no longer exists - so I have no expectation of finding parts)

Comment: @PeterM That’s a theory I suppose.